# How to remove leading zeros in Robot Framework?

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

```
Input : ${number}= 0000123
Output Should be : 123

@{random} = ['00123','3456']
@{random}[0] will have 00123
@{random}[0] should be equal to 123 (How to strip leading zero's ?)
```

How to remove/trim the leading zeros's in robot framework ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason you have leading zeroes is because it is a string, and not an integer. To convert a number there are two ways:

1. Assigning using the `${1234}` notation.
2. Converting to an integer using the `Convert To Integer` keyword. This is part of the `BuiltIn` standard library.

The following is the example code:

```
@{random_1}     Create List         00123    3456
${integer_1}    Set Variable          ${${random_1[0]}}
${integer_2}    Convert to Integer    ${random_1[0]}
```

However, conversion is always something we should prevent, so directly assigning the right type to the list is best.

```
@{random_2}     Create List         ${00123}    ${3456}
```